# How to apply css on the below code lines

Tags: css

```
var next_text=item.text().sub str(item.text().index Of("")+0,item.text().index Of("")+9);})
```

I wanted apply `css` property display none on the value `next_text`.How can i achieve that?

Comment: Please reformat your question. It has unnecessary spaces. It would help people to answer you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There must be Jquery object, On variable you can not apply css. Refer: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp